# Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard evaluation won't accept product code for brand new Windows Server 2019 Essentials

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

We have a DELL PowerEdge T640 purchased on January 2020 that has Windows Server 2019 Standard Evaluation which is due to expire very soon.

We have the Windows Server 2019 Essentials box with CD and a product code that we purchased a few months ago.

We have two remote engineers who use Microsoft Remote Desktop to frequently remote in to run engineering design tools.  Each guy has a local Windows account.

How do I upgrade our server without losing any data?

Here's the error we get when we try the Essential's product key.
Can we upgrade our Evaluation to Essentials?

[image]

Comment: What happened to the big fat warning that MS used to give about not running the evaluation in production?

Comment: You’re 200% correct! It’s not allowed to use Evaluational version in production, so OP got the trouble he basically begged for from the very beginning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that NP. Here’s one of the millions of these step-by-step guides on how to do that.

http://woshub.com/how-to-upgrade-windows-server-2016-evaluation-to-full-version/

Comment: 2nd answer seems to imply this answer can't work.  Trying "one of the millions" risks my team losing substantial development time if the upgrade loses data.  Awaiting Microsoft tech support to walk me through.  Will enter the answer here, if any.

Comment: You can’t lose any data if you run proper backups. If you don’t... scraping your SPOF properly won’t work.

Answer (score 0):

“Fixed” it by installing Windows Server 2019 Standard from the scratch.

Answer (score -1):

Windows Standard to Essential is not an upgrade, it's a downgrade.

You can't run DISM to make it accept the Essential's key as the tool accept only upgrade.

To give a quote for Datacenter to Standard;

> It is unable to upgrade from the Windows Server Eval Datacenter to
> Windows Server Standard Full.

I would issue a **DISM /online /Get-TargetEditions** to make sure. On a Windows Server 2019 Standard Eval this command let you upgrade to **Standard or Datacenter only**.

On a Windows Server Standard edition, the result of that command is;

[image]

I would plan to reconfigure if you really want an Essential's version. Check that [list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-essentials/install/add-windows-server-essentials-as-a-member-server) if the server would be a member of your Active Directory, as you would need to plan it correctly.

*Please make sure you can live with the Essential limitation if you go that path.*

Comment: What are the limitations?  We only have half a dozen users.  I though difference between Standard and Essential is that Essentials limits to 25 users.

Comment: @DougNull I don’t believe that’s all what’s cut out. Windows can up the features that’s pretty easy but there are probably deeper system differences that make a downgrade not really all that possible. In the same sense that increasing hard drive space on many cloud providers is easy... but decreasing space is a different ball game.